# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: database, duplicate

I installed one extension  and than

[image]

Comment: Sounds like this module is already installed, what's the content of your `core_resource` table, regarding this module ?

Comment: if i am not wrong, you said to look at the database table, seems that table didt created in db

Comment: Looks like the upgrade script of this extension is broken or has some conflict. Next step: uninstall it.

Comment: @fschmengler Thanks for your guidance, i will uninstall & install properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delete from core_resource where code='mpshippingmanager_setup';`

then try again.